# copy range of elements from an array to another array in C language

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, code-composer

i want to copy range of elements from existing array to new array. It will have a local integer array filled with an ID(just random numbers). It also has a global empty array having the same number of elements with the local array. My program contains a function, which copies the range of entries of the local array to the global array. this function will be as:

```
void func(int *ptr, int first, int last);
```

The ptr pointer will be used for the starting address of the local array. **first** indicates where copying begins. **last** indicates where copying ends. Btw, i'm using code composer and working with MSP430. Here is my code,

```
#include <msp430.h> 

int g_id[11];
int *ptr;
int *p;


int main(void) {

    WDTCTL = WDTPW | WDTHOLD;   // Stop watchdog timer
    
    int id[11]={5,0,1,8,3,5,1,4,0,9,1};
    int first = 3;
    int last= 8;
    ptr = id;
    p = g_id;

    for(ptr=&id[first]; *ptr < &id[last]; ptr++)
        {
            *p = *ptr;
            p++;         
        }

    while(1);
}
```

g_id is global array but i couldn't figure out.

last doesn't work and first was 3, program jump to 3 values and start with 8.
(8,3,5,1,4,0,9,1,0,0,0) but i want to see (0,0,0,8,3,5,1,4,0,0,0)

Comment: i added this line but didn't work, either : `*p = g_id[first];`

Comment: `*ptr < &id[last]` is a type error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting `p = g_id`. If you want the copy to go to matching locations, you have to set matching offsets on both the local and global arrays.

```
int *src, *dst;

for (src = id + first, dst = g_id + first; src <= id + last; src++, dst++) {
    *dst = *src;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To understand it better, use indexes instead of pointers:

```
for (int i = first; i <= last; i++) {
    g_id[i] = id[i];
}
```

Otherwise:

```
for (p = &g_id[first], ptr = &id[first]; ptr <= &id[last]; ptr++, p++) {
    *p = *ptr;
}
```